# (MS-ACCESS) Union Query Error - Order By Expression Includes Fields Not Selected by the Query

Tags: ms-access, sql-order-by, union

I am at a loss of where I am going wrong here. I am not accustomed to MS-ACCESS' syntax, so this is compounding my problem. I have two databases that I need to access information from and join together into a unified dataset. I am attempting to execute the following union query, but I keep getting errors. Any advice?

```
    SELECT RT.USR_03_TEXT AS WORK_CTR,
Sum([TS.DMD_ACTL_QTY] * [RT.UOM_ALT_2_FCTR]) AS ORDERED,
Sum([RT.UOM_ALT_2_FCTR] * [TS.USR_03_QTY]) AS OFFSET_FC,
ORDERED / OFFSET_FC AS ATTMT
FROM dbo_SCP_FCST_ROOT AS RT
INNER JOIN dbo_SCP_FCST_TIME_SERIES AS TS
ON RT.SCP_SEQ_NBR = TS.SCP_SEQ_NBR
WHERE (((TS.FCST_YR_PRD) BETWEEN Format(DateAdd("m", - 3, DATE ()), "yyyymm") AND Format(DateAdd("m", - 1, DATE ()), "yyyymm")))

UNION

SELECT RT_UK.USR_03_TEXT AS WORK_CTR,
Sum([TS_UK.DMD_ACTL_QTY] * [RT_UK.UOM_ALT_2_FCTR]) AS ORDERED, 
Sum([RT_UK.UOM_ALT_2_FCTR] * [TS_UK.USR_03_QTY]) AS OFFSET_FC,
ORDERED / OFFSET_FC AS ATTMT
FROM dbo_SCP_FCST_ROOT_UK AS RT_UK
INNER JOIN dbo_SCP_FCST_TIME_SERIES_UK AS TS_UK
ON RT_UK.SCP_SEQ_NBR = TS_UK.SCP_SEQ_NBR
WHERE (((TS_UK.FCST_YR_PRD) BETWEEN Format(DateAdd("m", - 3, DATE ()), "yyyymm") AND Format(DateAdd("m", - 1, DATE ()), "yyyymm")))
GROUP BY WORK_CTR
ORDER BY WORK_CTR;
```

Comment: You miss _Group By_ in the first query.

Comment: Does the error go away if you change `ORDER BY WORK_CTR` to `ORDER BY 1`?  Or do you get a different error?

Comment: No, I tried that but it didn’t work either. I have run each statement separately and they work fine. It has something specifically to Do with the union, but I can’t figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Provide example data. Try removing the ORDER BY. Build another query that pulls from the UNION and include ORDER BY there. Did you add the GROUP BY into the first SELECT? Edit question.